# Get the id of a record in the url and display it in another lightning component

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components

I have a lightning component that display a list of sObject :

```
  <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}"/>
  <aura:registerEvent name="articleDetail" type="c:Z_ArticleToDetailEvent"/>
  <aura:attribute name="lstArticles" type="Article__c[]"/>
  <aura:attribute name="id" type="String"/>

    <aura:iteration items="{!v.lstArticles}" var="article">
            <li class="list-group-item">
                    <a href="{! '?articleId=' + article.Id }" onclick="{!c.onArticleChange}" aura:id="selectedArticle">
                            <p>{!article.Name}</p>
                            <p>{!article.Prix__c}</p>
                    </a>
            </li>
    </aura:iteration>

<!--the other component is called here :-->
<div>
    <c:Z_DetailArticle articleId="id" selectedArticle="{!v.SelArt}" />
</div>
```

In the `<a href="{! '?articleId=' + article.Id }"` I set the new url so I can have the id of the record I selected in the url.
What I want is to get that id (in the url) in the other component to display for example the name of the selected Article__c.

I did that in the other component :

```
<aura:attribute name="selectedArticle" type="String"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<aura:handler event="c:Z_ArticleToDetailEvent" action="{!c.setSelectedArticle}"/>
<aura:attribute name="object" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="articleId" type="String"/>

id = {!v.articleId}
```

But I don't know how to get the id in this second component.

**Update**
Here is the controller js of the first component, where I try to get the id and pass it to the event

```
onArticleChange : function(component, event, helper){
    //here, the selectedArticle return undefined in the console log
    var selectedArticle = component.get("v.article.Id");
    console.log("article selected : " + selectedArticle);
    component.set("v.SelArt",selectedArticle);

    console.log("got the selectedAccount: "+selectedArticle);
    var articleEvent = $A.get("e.c:Z_ArticleToDetailEvent");
    articleEvent.setParams({
      "article": selectedArticle
    });
    articleEvent.fire();

},
```

Comment: you can pass them as event parameter.

Comment: @TusharSharma Sharma Yes I use an event and a parameter that is mean to get the id and pass it to the second component, but I am not able to get the id in the first place (and then pass it in the parameter of the event) I just edited the question